# Left and Right Concatenation in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I have this code which produces the date in `DDMMYYYY` format:

```
REPLACE(CONVERT(CHAR(10), JOBR_GENERIC.DATE_ATTR1, 103), '/', '') AS DATE_ATTR1
```

I want to have the format like this: `DDMMYY`. How can I do this in SQL?

Comment: What [tag:rdbms] are you using?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: SQL Server I am using

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`FORMAT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

```
SELECT FORMAT(GETDATE(), 'ddMMyy', 'en-US' )
```

Or in your example:

```
SELECT FORMAT(JOBR_GENERIC.DATE_ATTR1, 'ddMMyy', 'en-US' )
```

Comment: Where do I put the field: JOBR_GENERIC.DATE_ATTR1?

Comment: 'FORMAT IS NOT A BUILT IN FUNCTION NAME'

Comment: this is the error I am getting, can I not use left and right concatenation?

Comment: It looks like you're using an old version of SQL Server that doesn't support the FORMAT function. You can go with John's answer instead.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are not on 2012+.  Here's another option

**Example**

```
Select replace(convert(varchar(8),GetDate(),5),'-','')
```

**Returns**

```
260618
```